# How do I import Pandas library into PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have downloaded Pandas library with `pip install pandas` through the command prompt, when I try to `import pandas as pd` PyCharm returns an error : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

I have tried to uninstall and install again many times but nothing seems to work. Does anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: Do you have both python 2 and python 3 installed (a common setup on Linux)? It may be that you have installed pandas with the other version of Python than the one that you are running when you try the import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try downloading the library from PyCharm settings:

1. File -> Settings
2. then, Project:  -> Python Interpreter
3. Click a `+` sign to the right,
4. Search for the `pandas` library,
5. and finally, press 'Install Package'

Comment: After doing these steps.. no more error message. I believe this is the solution

Comment: This is an easy way to install any version of any library, instead of other, more complex ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to choose the right `python interpreter`. Check my screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You likely have multiple copies of Python installed on your system. PyCharm can be configured to use any version of Python on your system, including any virtual environments you've defined.  The solution is to match up the version of Python you've installed Pandas into with the version of Python that PyCharm is using to run your code.

There are two places where you specify a Python version.  First of all, your Project has a version associated with it.  Check the "Python Interpreter" section of the "Project" section of your Preferences for that.  That version is used for syntax highlighting, code completion, etc.

By default, the abovementioned Python version will also be used to run your code.  But you can change the version of Python that your code is run with by creating or modifying a Run Configuration.  To do this, check the menu next to the Run and Debug toolbar buttons near the top-left of your PyCharm window.

When you do get into the Python Interpreter section of the Preferences, you'll find that you can see all of the modules installed for each Python version that PyCharm knows about.  You can use this to check to see if Pandas is installed for a particular Python version.

I would suggest you get comfortable with all that I've said above. It will save you many headaches in the future.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Clicking the little "wrench" icon will bring up Preferences, or you can get at it from the menubar as well. Menu: PyCharm -> Preferences (on Mac anyway...maybe different on Windows).

Comment: I just added a little more info to the answer.  Find the "Project Interpreter" section of the Preferences.  It is key that you know how that works. - If the interpreter you want to use, the one containing Pandas, isn't there, you may need to add it. Alternately, you can add Pandas to whichever interpreter version it is currently using.

Comment: I think another reply has solved the issue. I went into 'Project interpreter' and manually searched for the 'pandas' library, now no more error message.