# Tensorflow package is not found when running python program

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a super simple Python setup generated through PyCharm:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, optimizers, utils, datasets


def print_hi(name):
    print(f'Hi, {name}')  # Press Ctrl+F8 to toggle the breakpoint.


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')
```

When I run it, it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\max\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, optimizers, utils, datasets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

But the package is installed, I can see it here in the virtual env:

[image]

I suspect it might be looking for the package in the global env, not virtual env. How to check that?

I see the following interpreters. Tried selecting both, none worked.

[image]

Comment: Look at the lower right corner of your PyCharm window to see the active interpreter version in the status bar. You can click that to select another interpreter.

Comment: As an aside, please don't post code that conflicts with your traceback (in effect, don't deceive us). The imports are on line 2 in your program, and your traceback mentions line 7.

Comment: @AKX, sorry, I posted the code without comments at the top that added a few lines, will keep that in mind next time. So regarding the interpreters, I see this (added to the quetstion). Not sure how that should help me with the issue. I tried selecting both, still the same error.

Comment: You could try remove the interpreter via Interpreter Settings and create a new interpreter using that `venv`, just in case.

Comment: @AKX, all right, will try that as well, but could you maybe say a few sentences to enhance my understanding of why changing the interperter my help?

Comment: The interpreter (in PyCharm's terms) is the selected python version and possibly associated virtualenv or other environment (conda etc.). It looks like your PyCharm is executing the wrong, or at least misconfigured interpreter, so the `tensorflow` package in that venv isn't found. @LoukasPap's answer basically just installs tensorflow via PyCharm into the interpreter configured, which sidesteps the actual problem.

Comment: @AKX Got it, thanks. Do you think PyCharm adds some [import hooks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks) to configure how packages are resolved by the interpreter?

Comment: No, it absolutely doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the procedure in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66016514/9714255.
It downloads the module through PyCharm for `pandas` but it's the same for `tensorflow`.

---

You can have as many Python interpreters you want. Each one is stored through PyCharm, in the path `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<version>` and you can find your installed packages in the `Lib` folder (following the previous path first). Each interpreter has its own packages, and when you downloaded `tensorflow` (like above), it was added as a package in this interpreter, and so you are able to use it. You can have many interpreters with different packages in each one.

I am not sure, but I also think python interpreters correspond to the python version you use.

This link might be helpful: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#interpreter.

Comment: this worked, thanks! but could you maybe elaborate on the `why`? where did it install it so that other innstallations didn't pick it up?

Comment: I will update my answer explaining it.

Comment: Does my explanation makes it any more clear? @MaxKoretskyi

Comment: yes, thanks! i'm just wondering what interperter the venv I showed on the screenshot belonged to, b/c it had tensorflow installed but none of interpreters could find it